# Help with discrete mathematics - inference and logical equivalence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I'm doing textbook homework for discrete mathematics and I'm struggling to understand how to solve the following practice problem. I would understand if they gave me variables and asked me to use premises to construct a specific argument, but I don't understand how to reduce it just to a value of false? Any help or hints would be appreciated.

Question:

Using only the rules of inference and the logical equivalences, show that the following argument is a contradiction by reducing it to a value of
"False". You may assume that all the premises given are true.

→

¬ ∧

¬ →

→ ¬

∧ f

Comment: It seems like these are five premises, but you haven't given the conclusion.  Is this really all there is to the exercise?  It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: From 3 and 4 derive $\lnot a \to \lnot e$. Then use it and 1 with $a \lor \lnot a$ to apply [Dilemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_dilemma)  to derive  $\lnot e \lor b$.

Comment: Yeah, this is all that was given. I don't really understand it.

Comment: Now you have $\lnot e \lor b$ with $\lnot b$ from 2 and $e$ from 5.

Comment: Is it enough to proceed, or do you need more hints ?

Comment: More hints would be appreciated. I'm still confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implication $a \to b$ is equivalent to $\lnot a \lor b$

Similarly, the other two implications can be written as $a \lor d$ and $\lnot d \lor \lnot e$

The two conjunctions $\lnot b \land c$ and $e \land f$ can only be true, if all four operands are true: $\lnot b$, $c$, $e$ and $f$

This simplifies $\lnot a \lor b$ to $\lnot a$

$\lnot d \lor \lnot e$ is simplified to $\lnot d$ which in turn simplifies $a \lor d$ to $a$.

The last step unveils a contradiction, as $\lnot a$ was found to be true earlier on.